# javascrip sort array of objects with different keys

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "2019-10-01": false
    },
    {
        "2020-04-01": true
    },
    {
        "2020-02-01": true
    },
    {
        "2018-01-01": false
    },
    {
        "2019-12-01": true
    }
]
```

I want to sort the objects by the dates, which are the keys. What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys irrespective of their name and compare the date strings with [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "2019-10-01": false
    },
    {
        "2020-04-01": true
    },
    {
        "2020-02-01": true
    },
    {
        "2018-01-01": false
    },
    {
        "2019-12-01": true
    }
]

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  let [ aDate ] = Object.keys(a)
  let [ bDate ] = Object.keys(b)
  return aDate.localeCompare(bDate)
})

console.info(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.keys` to get the array from Object keys and sorting using `Date` instance.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "2019-10-01": false
    },
    {
        "2020-04-01": true
    },
    {
        "2020-02-01": true
    },
    {
        "2018-01-01": false
    },
    {
        "2019-12-01": true
    }
]

data = data.sort((a, b) => 
  new Date(Object.keys(a)[0]) - new Date(Object.keys(b)[0])
)

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

```js
var a = [
    {
        "2019-10-01": false
    },
    {
        "2020-04-01": true
    },
    {
        "2020-02-01": true
    },
    {
        "2018-01-01": false
    },
    {
        "2019-12-01": true
    }
]
a.sort((a, b) => {
 return (new Date(Object.keys(a))) -(new Date(Object.keys(b)))
})
```

Comment: That's a neat trick with the single array `toString()` in the `Date` constructor but you'll quickly run into problems if there's more than one key. That probably rings true for all the answers though 